# C# Return statement with auto-increment value

Tags: c#, return, auto-increment

Is there a reason why these 2 examples do not produce the same value.
C # doesn't seem to auto-increment before returning.

```
        nextNumber++;
        return nextNumber;
```

and

```
 return nextNumber++;
```

Is it a bug?
I am using
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.7.6

Comment: post increment operator execute after return.

Comment: It is not a bug. If you want the same result, it should be "return ++nextNumber". In the other case, the addition is performed after the value is returned.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nope, check this out:

```cs
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(t1(1));
        Console.WriteLine(t2(1));
        Console.WriteLine(t3(1));
    }
    
    private static int  t1(int nextNumber)
    {
         return nextNumber++;       
    }
    
    private static int  t2(int nextNumber)
    {
        nextNumber++;
        return nextNumber;  
    }
    
    private static int t3(int nextNumber)
    {
        return ++nextNumber;    
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/4fna9w

outputs:

```
1
2
2
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#increment-operator-

> the postfix increment operator, x++, and the prefix increment operator, ++x.

Check the examples on the doc.

Comment: Thank you, I never realized that.